# Como traer 2 datos por ajax y graficar en una sola

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, chart.js

Necesito colocar una grafica de diferencia venta x gasto. Traigo los datos por medio de jquery y consulta en la base de datos, estoy estancado porque no sé como enviar los datos por separados a uno solo, o si se puede un solo jquery para hacer las 2 consultas distintas

Esta es la consulta para traer la venta:

```
    function datagrafico2(base_url, year) {
      namesMonth = ["Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic"];
      $.ajax({
        url: base_url + "Admin/getData?id=<?= $perfil->sede_id ?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          year: year
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          var dias = new Array();
          var montos = new Array();
          $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            dias.push(namesMonth[value.mes - 1]);
            valor = Number(value.monto);
            montos.push(valor);
          });
          grafica(dias, montos);
        }
      });
```

Y esta es la consulta para traer los gastos:

```
    function gasto2(base_url, year) {
      namesMonth = ["Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic"];
      $.ajax({
        url: base_url + "Admin/getDataGasto?id=<?= $perfil->sede_id ?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          year: year
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          var dias = new Array();
          var montos = new Array();
          $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            dias.push(namesMonth[value.mes - 1]);
            valor = Number(value.monto);
            montos.push(valor);
          });
          grafica(dias, montos);
        }
      });
    }
```

y este es el codigo que dibuja la grafica, en el momento solo tengo dibujando la venta y en gastos no tengo acomodado los valores

```
   function grafica(dias, montos) {

      var options = {
        chart: {
          type: 'bar',
          events: {
            dataPointSelection: function(event, chartContext, config) {
              var fecha = config.w.globals.categoryLabels[config.dataPointIndex];
              $.ajax({
                url: base_url + "Admin/view?id=<?= $perfil->sede_id ?>",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "html",
                data: {
                  fecha: fecha
                },
                success: function(data) {
                  $('#myModal').modal('show'); {
                    $('.modal-body').html(data)
                  }
                }
              });
            }
          }
        },
        series: [{
          name: 'monto',
          data: montos
        }],

        stroke: {
          show: true,
          width: 3
        },

        plotOptions: {
          bar: {
            columnWidth: '100%',
            distributed: true,
          }
        },
        xaxis: {
          labels: {
            rotate: -45
          },
          categories: dias,
          tickPlacement: 'on'
        },
        yaxis: {
          title: {
            text: 'Dias',
          },
        },
      }

      var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart2"), options);

      chart.render();
    }
```

Si necesitan que adjunte el controlador y modelo de cada consulta me dicen, lo tengo todo con codeigniter

esta era la consulta que traia a gasto

```
public function montosMesesGasto($year,$id){
    $this->db->select("MONTH(fecha) as mes, SUM(monto) as monto");
    $this->db->from("gastos");
    $this->db->where("fecha >=",$year."-01-01");
    $this->db->where("fecha <=",$year."-12-31");
    $this->db->where("sede_id",$id);
    $this->db->group_by("mes");
    $this->db->order_by("mes");
    $resultados = $this->db->get();
    return $resultados->result();
}
```

y este es la de venta

```
public function montosMesesGasto($year,$id){
        $this->db->select("MONTH(fecha) as mes, SUM(monto) as monto");
        $this->db->from("venta");
        $this->db->where("fecha >=",$year."-01-01");
        $this->db->where("fecha <=",$year."-12-31");
        $this->db->where("sede_id",$id);
        $this->db->group_by("mes");
        $this->db->order_by("mes");
        $resultados = $this->db->get();
        return $resultados->result();
    }
```

Comment: Creo que le falta mas contexto y explicación a tu pregunta, recuerda que puedes [Editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/552269/edit) tu pregunta las veces que sean necesarias. Por otro lado, no es mas conveniente traer los datos relacionados desde una sola consulta, así evitarías realizar dos peticiones y obtendrías los datos como los requieres.

Comment: Robinson debes hacer "separación de intereses" (separation of concerns), es decir, primero realizas la carga la datos (asíncrona en este caso) y luego te preocupas por la visualización. Con [$.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) puedes hacer varios llamados a tus apis al mismo tiempo lo cual te podría ayudar con la carga de los datos, luego cuando ese proceso termina y tengas acceso a los datos te será más fácil acomodar la información que deseas mostrar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realicé la opción de antonio y realicé una consulta en una sola. Voy a editar la pregunta para revisar la consulta, así quedó lo de una sola consulta

```
SELECT MONTH(ve.fecha_actualizacion) AS mes, SUM(ve.total) AS montov , 
    (SELECT  SUM(ga.monto) AS monto
        FROM gastos ga
        WHERE MONTH(ga.fecha)= MONTH(ve.fecha_actualizacion)
        AND ga.sede_id=1
        AND ga.fecha >='2022-01-01'
        AND ga.fecha <='2022-12-31') gastov                 
FROM venta ve
WHERE ve.fecha_actualizacion >='2022-01-01'
AND ve.fecha_actualizacion <='2022-12-31'
AND ve.sede_id = 1
GROUP BY 1;
```